# How to use SOAP in enyo?

Tags: javascript, web-services, webos, enyo

For the last two days I have been searching for an answer to this question.

1. Does Enyo support SOAP? If not, is there an alternative to SOAP?
2. How can we call web services using JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific SOAP support in Enyo.  You could likely find another JS library supporting SOAP and wrap it up in an Enyo kind.

Enyo 1.0 has a Web Service kind.
Enyo 2.0 currently just exposes an Ajax control to use instead.

If you decide to use something other than SOAP, I'd recommend the service return JSON.  If you must use SOAP, you'll need to extend Enyo yourself to support it.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred method is JSON Services, though you can also use XML Services...

Here is a link to how to use web services in the Enyo Framework.

[Web Services in Enyo](https://developer.palm.com/content/api/dev-guide/enyo/web-service.html)